# How can I add a value to a Pydantic model (not instance)

Tags: python, pydantic

Is there a way to store a set value with a Pydantic model (not each instance of the model)? In the code below, `slack_members` is a global variable. I'd like to have it self-contained within the model. This would allow for easier testing and better protability. Or is there a way to pass in the `slack_members` value to the `email()` function? I could store it with each instance, but that would be very inefficient since `slack_members` can contain hundreds of items. Or any other alternatives would be appreciated.

```
class Allocation(BaseModel):
    person: str
    hours: int

    @property
    def email(self):
        member = slack_members.match_user(self.person)
        return member.email
```

Comment: "I could store it with each instance, but that would be very inefficient since slack_members can contain hundreds of items." why would it be very inefficient?

Comment: Anyway, you can just use `typing.ClassVar` to annotate something as a class variable. so in this case, you could do `slack_members: typing.ClassVar = slack_members`

Comment: I think it would be inefficient because it would store a new copy of slack_members with every instance of Allocation.

Comment: But I will try the Classvar. Thank you

Comment: It wouldn't store a new copy unless you explicitly made a copy. If you just pass in the global variable, it will not make a copy.